# php pcre extra brakets

Tags: php, regex

```
 $regex = '/<A HREF="(.*)">(1080p)</A><BR>/i';
 preg_match_all($regex, $homepage, $matches);
```

How would I stop preg_match from trying to find 1080p and just find (.*).

```
<b>(Yahoo)</b><br>
<b>(High Definition)</b><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193280&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(1080p)</a><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193279&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(720p)</a><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193272&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(480p)</a><br>
<br>
<b>(Warner Bros.)</b><br>
<b>(High Definition)</b><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_1080.mov">(1080p)</a><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_720.mov">(720p)</a><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_480.mov">(480p)</a><br>
</p>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Do you have `(1080p)` text in `$homepage`? Escape the parentheses if you have, like this  `/<A HREF="(.*)">\(1080p\)</A><BR>/i` Or remove them if you do not have them in the original text

Comment: yes I do have the (1080p) text in $homepage escaping them is not working

Comment: Show us this part from `$homepage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 1080p into a non-capturing group:

```
$regex = '#<A HREF="(.*)">(?:1080p)</A><BR>#i';
```

Or better yet, eliminate the group:

```
$regex = '#<A HREF="(.*)">1080p</A><BR>#i';
```

If you have "(1080p)" as the string, escape the parenthesis:

```
$regex = '#<A HREF="(.*)">\(1080p\)</A><BR>#i';
```

Here's a better regex for your application;

```
$regex = '#<a href="([^"]+)">\(\d{3,4}p\)</a><br>#i';
$html  = '<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_1080.mov">(1080p)</a><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_720.mov">(720p)</a><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_480.mov">(480p)</a><br>';
preg_match_all( $regex, $html, $matches);

var_dump( $matches[1]);
```

Output: [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/S0NDR1)

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(75) "http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_1080.mov"
  [1]=>
  string(74) "http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_720.mov"
  [2]=>
  string(74) "http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_480.mov"
}
```

Comment: (1080p) is part of of the text in $homepage

Comment: Thanks, but i already tried that.
here is a sample of what I am trying to filter the links from 
<b>(High Definition)</b><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193280&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(1080p)</a><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193279&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(720p)</a><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193272&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(480p)</a><br>
<br>

Comment: Edit that into your OP (use the code formatting so it doesn't get parsed as HTML) and I can create a regex for you to use.

Comment: Try these edits - I overlooked that you used forward slash in the regex - You need a unique delimiter character, so instead of slash these use `#`.